# Is it safe to update Linux Mint 17.1 repositories to Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

Linux Mint releases are always based on the yearly LTS version of Ubuntu. While LTS is great for its stability, it doesn't really seek cutting-edge versions like the regular versions (or should I call LTS the regular version?), containing a few outdated packages and applications.

The current version of Linux Mint (as of this question's date) is Rebecca (17.1), based on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (14.04), which is close to be one year old.

My question is: Is it safe to update Linux Mint's repositories to match Ubuntu's, replacing `trusty` with `utopic` in the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: I'd really like to know this too. Linux Mint repositories don't contain gnuCash which I need so I added the Trusty Tahr 14.04 repository and everything has been working fine. However, I now want to upgrade gnuCash and the new version is only in Utopic 14.10. I imagine that it is probably fairly safe to update the repositories but that's just because I think there isn't likely to be huge differences between 14.10 and 14.04. Would love someone who knows more to answer this question.
Cheers :-)

Comment: Well I'm going ahead and trying it. PM me if I forget to post back here with the results ;-)

Comment: Well, any news on that? How did you end up to? Hope you computer didn't explode..

Comment: Sorry i forgot like I thought I might. :-/
I'm can't remember what i did, I assume I did what I said I would and my computer didn't explode. But if I look at my repositories now all the ubuntu ones are still set to Trusty Tahr. So I don't think there is too much harm is testing. I must have survived, but I can't remember what actually happened. sorry :-(